# Magento 2 Cannot update specialPrice per website

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, price, special-price

I'm trying to update specialPrice per website in a Magento 2.3.6 website. The problem is that when i am updating the price using the Product model , the specialPrice is removed from all storeviews ( prices scope is set to website ), and as a result i have the default websites special price for all my storeviews.

```
$productInStore= $this->productRepository->getById($productId, true, $storeId);
$productInStore->setPrice($storePrice);
$productInStore->setSpecialPrice($storeDiscount);
$this->productRepository->save($productInStore);
```

I am able to fix the issue by using the **updateAttributes** method from **\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action**.

There are two problems with the above solution

1. The next time someone tries to save the product using repository / model , the prices are immediately invalidated.
2. It does not feel right

I've digged in the Magento source and i've found a weird piece of code beeing executed in **Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price**

```
public function afterSave($object)
{
    /** @var $attribute \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute */
    $attribute = $this->getAttribute();
    $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
    $value = $object->getData($attributeCode);
    // $value may be passed as null to unset the attribute
    if ($value === null || (float)$value > 0) {
        if ($attribute->isScopeWebsite() && $object->getStoreId() != \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID) {
            if ($this->isUseDefault($object)) {
                $value = null;
            }
            foreach ((array)$object->getWebsiteStoreIds() as $storeId) {
                $object->addAttributeUpdate($attributeCode, $value, $storeId);
            }
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see, the line that is causing me this issue is the one bellow

```
$attribute->isScopeWebsite() && $object->getStoreId() != \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
```

Although it doesnt makes sense, let me explain...
I've set the store id to number 2 ( which is the store id / under the website that i want the price to be different ). It checks that the Price attribute is scoped per website, and then it checks if the attribute in the product is 0.

So there is no way to update the price in different store views as long this check exists.

Is there any other way to overcome this issue? Am the one one strugling with this one ? ( did not find any related info around the web )

Comment: please add the piece of code which shows how you loaded `$productInStore` object.

Comment: I've just updated my question

Comment: My hunch looking at this is that if you want a different special price per store view you may have to change price scope to be at store view level too?